# Differentiating $f(x)=\lim_{N \to \infty} N^{x}\prod_{k=1}^{N}\frac{k}{x+k}$

Tags: limits, derivatives

#### Introducing the Function

Online I found a function that generalizes the factorial that isn't the gamma function. I feel that this function is better then the gamma function because it gets accurate way quicker and it is easier to understand. Here is the function:

$$f(x)=\lim_{N \to \infty} N^{x}\prod_{k=1}^{N}\frac{k}{x+k}$$

I prefer this function because it it so much more easily calculated. At N = 40 (ignoring the limit) the function is almost identical to x!

#### My Problem

I cannot figure out how to find the derivative of this function because the limit is in the way. If someone could show me or give me a hint to how to get around the limit that would be very useful.

#### Making my question better

Please comment on how I could improve this question if it is unclear. This is important to me so in the future I can ask better questions. This is also important so that if anyone finds this post trying to figure out the same thing I am they will understand what I am talking about.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you know about the convergence of the formula for $f$? Is $x$ restricted to be real, or can it be complex? At any rate, the first thing I think of when considering the derivative of a limit function is whether or not the convergence is uniform on compact sets, and whether the derivatives of the terms of the sequence converge.

Comment: What if I told you $f(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$? Your function is in fact just the gamma function in disguise. There are quite a few well known ways (like this one) to express the gamma function; see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html#:~:text=The%20(complete)%20gamma%20function%20is,1812%3B%20Edwards%202001%2C%20p.).

Comment: Yes but the reason I chose this function over the gamma function is because the gamma function is not as well defined for negative values of x

Comment: @AlexBeam I think you can take logarithm and differentiate, given that the limit exists.

Comment: You're confusing a function for its representation. Your function IS precisely the (shifted) gamma function. It is however a different **representation** of the gamma function; just because this representation doesn't look like the standard representation you're used to doesn't mean it's not the same old gamma function. The fact that the gamma function has so many equivalent representations is part of why its so useful. Now, my question is, do you want to know how to differentiate the gamma function using this particular representation, or just differentiate the gamma function in general?

Comment: @AlexBeam The gamma function $\Gamma(x+1)$ is perfectly well defined for negative values (except for negative integers).

Comment: What I meant is that for negative numbers like -3.5 is not defined in the gamma function

Comment: The gamma function is defined for all complex numbers other than the non-positive integers. For example, $\Gamma(-3.5)=\frac{16\sqrt{\pi}}{105}$. The common representation simply doesn't apply to $\Gamma(z)$ for $z$ with real part $\leq 0$. It might be a good idea to give the Wiki and Wolfram articles I linked a good read. It might help a bit to clear up your confusion between a function's representation and the function itself (and even if it doesn't, you can learn some cool things about the gamma function).

Comment: Oh ok I see what you are saying. It was my mistake because I entered the gamma function onto Desmos and it didn't show the negative parts. I should have tried to enter negative values into Gamma instead of immediately assuming that it wasn't defined for those numbers. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @C-RAM Responding to your question before I would like to know how to differentiate this exact representation of the gamma function. Thank you for explaining that this is still the gamma function with a different representation. After this experience I have learned a lot more about the gamma function and I now know that I should research a problem before posting it to stack exchange

Comment: You are right to be hesitant about exchanging the limit and the derivative. Any time you exchange two operations defined by limits, there is a possibility the result will change. That said, that possibility is usually restricted to fringe cases. The normal practice is to not worry about it and exchange them, and if it doesn't blow up in your face, go back and see if you can justify the answer. In this case, it may be helpful to take the logarithmic derivative $\frac{f'}f$.

Comment: Ok thank you this comment section really helped with my question because I know how to take the derivative of the gamma function. Thanks everyone!